# Large USN value in Evernote initial sync

Tags: java, evernote

I am trying to sync an evernote account using Java program, below is the code sample for it

```
NoteStoreClient noteStoreClient = clientFactory.createNoteStoreClient();
SyncChunk syncChunk = noteStoreClient.getSyncChunk(0, 200, true);

while (true) {
     List<Note> noteListforCurrentChunk = syncChunk.getNotes();
     //Sync to DB
     syncChunk = noteStoreClient.getSyncChunk(syncChunk.getChunkHighUSN(), 200, true);
     if (syncChunk.getChunkHighUSN() == syncChunk.getUpdateCount()) {
       return;
     }
}
```

The first call to syncChunk.getChunkHighUSN() returns 1187 for my user, which results in no notes being retrieved. This is happening to some accounts only

Can anyone help on this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to create a filter to make it working. Now i am able to retrieve all the notes under this notebook

```
SyncChunkFilter filter = new SyncChunkFilter();
filter.setIncludeNotes(true);
NoteStoreClient noteStoreClient = clientFactory.createNoteStoreClient();
SyncChunk syncChunk = noteStoreClient.getFilteredSyncChunk(0, 200, filter);

while (true) {
     List<Note> noteListforCurrentChunk = syncChunk.getNotes();
     //Sync to DB
     syncChunk = noteStoreClient.getFilteredSyncChunk(syncChunk.getChunkHighUSN(), 200, filter);
     if (syncChunk.getChunkHighUSN() == syncChunk.getUpdateCount()) {
       return;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's some quote on USN from [the doc](http://dev.evernote.com/media/pdf/edam-sync.pdf).

> The USNs within an account start at “1” (for the first object created in the account) and then increase
>   monotonically every time an object is created, modified, or deleted. The server keeps track of the
>   “update count” for each account, which is identical to the highest USN that has been assigned.

So, the higher number of USN doesn't always mean you have many notes. It just indicates that the user has done some operations on its account.